# Program stopping when trying to rotate an image

Tags: android, image, animation, imageview, rotateanimation

I am new to android programming and am trying to rotate an image.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView x; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        x = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.clippedneedle); 
        RotateAnimation newAnim = new RotateAnimation(0,360); 
        newAnim.setFillAfter(true); 
        newAnim.setDuration(10); 
        x.startAnimation(newAnim); 

    }
}
```

My layout file is standard and just contains code from an ImageView.

Basically, my program stops running as soon as it opens. The logcat says that the thread is exiting with uncaught exception.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you post your full logcat error stacktrace?

Comment: I edited my answer and added some code at the bottom. I have tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the id of a `Drawable` here:

```
x = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.clippedneedle);
```

You need to pass the id of an `ImageView`. If you have an `ImageView` in `R.layout.activity_main`, do the following:

```
x = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageViewId);
x.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clippedneedle
```

Here's your code with a few changes:

```
x = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.clippedneedle); 
RotateAnimation newAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f); 
newAnim.setFillAfter(true); 
newAnim.setDuration(2000);    // 2 seconds || 2000 milliseconds 
x.startAnimation(newAnim);
```

There is much more that you can do here. Take a look at [Android developer's resource page on Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html).

Comment: or just x.setImageResource(R.drawable. clippedneedle);

Comment: Not sure where I read about setImageDrawable(Drawable) being more efficient than setImageResource(int). Not that it would matter in this case.

Comment: thanks the program runs now but it doesn't rotate.. do you know why this may be occurring?